# Webdriver: java.lang.AssertionError: An Error has occureed whilst waiting for the 'Ajax Loader Screen' to disappear?

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a method which waits for an ajax loader screen to disappear, when running my project in Jenkins i get the odd build which fails and i cant understand why?

```
    public boolean waitUntilAjaxElementDisapears() {
    // Wait up to 2minutes for the element to disappear
    WebDriverWait ajaxWait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, 120);
    try {
        Boolean elementPresent = ajaxWait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".ajax_loader")));
        if (elementPresent == true) {
            ajaxWait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".ajax_loader")));
            System.out.println("The 'Ajax Loader Screen' has now Disappeared!");
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("An Error has occureed whilst waiting for the 'Ajax Loader Screen' to disappear, using locator: "+ ".ajax_loader ,Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        Assert.fail("An Error has occureed whilst waiting for the 'Ajax Loader Screen' to disappear, using locator: .ajax_loader ");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Exceptions which are raised (Logged) within jenkins, seems to be an odd build which would report the exception listed below:

```
[79.984][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 60.000
[79.994][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.010
May 23, 2017 1:14:20 AM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.cssSelector: .ajax_loader)
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10240 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 59.85 seconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'BG146', ip: '172.16.2.162', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233), userDataDir=C:\Users\GIANNI~1.BRU\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6584_12530}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.110, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore}]
Session ID: 06dcd6841a25d4c64139981c6ff37420
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=.ajax_loader}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:437)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:505)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElements(By.java:441)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:398)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:882)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$20.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:580)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$20.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:576)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:209)
    at BuyAGiftFramework.pageObjects.Base_Page.waitUntilAjaxElementDisapears(Base_Page.java:472)
    at BuyAGiftFramework.complete.AddingDrivingExperienceToBasketTest.clickOn_PaySecurelyNowButton(AddingDrivingExperienceToBasketTest.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Are you sure the loader disappeared?

Comment: @Guy I cannot see it in the error screenshot, im thinking to maybe extend the wait time on the method

Comment: Let us know how it goes. By the way, did you try running it locally without Jenkins?

Comment: ok @Guy will do, I have run the framework locally, on a local machine using jenkins and a virtual machine using jenkins

Comment: I usually just eat such errors.  If something is really wrong it will fail anyway soon.  A theory is that the wait starts too soon.  I have had some success with sleeping for 500 milliseconds before starting the wait.